# Why all the weird classes when importing ASP.NET web services?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I need to call an ASP.NET web service from an external company. For simplicity's sake, let's say the interface I expect looks something like this:

```
public interface MyIntf
{
    byte[] downloadFile(string userName, string password, DateTime fileDate);
}
```

When I import the WSDL using Visual Studio 2012, I instead get an interface like this:

```
public interface MyIntf
{
    MyNamespace.DownloadFileResponse downloadFile(MyNamespace.DownloadFileRequest);
}
```

Of course there are also classes to support this definition: DownloadFileResponse, DownloadFileResponseBody, DownloadFileRequest and DownloadFileRequestBody.

This makes calling the function an enormous pain, especially since the actual interface has several methods and some have only a single parameter.

I know that I have previously imported web services and gotten the expected definition, so what's causing Visual Studio to complicate my life now?

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to consume it as a `WebService` have you tried consuming it as a `Service` in `VS2012` and seeing if the proper web methods get exposed and or WSDL get imported in..? can you share the Web Service URL..?

Comment: Actually, I just added a service reference. I initially didn't understand your comment until I noticed the "Add Web Reference" button buried away behind the Advanced button. I tried that and it worked like a charm. Now if you only added the answer, I could accept it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are trying to consume it as a WebService have you tried consuming it as a Service in VS2012 and seeing if the proper web methods get exposed and or WSDL get imported in..? can you share the Web Service URL..?